# What is the difference between Meditation and Penance?

Tags: yoga, meditation, mind

- People doing **Penance** are in meditation posture.
- **Meditating** people are also in same posture.
- **Penance have goals** to achieve and **Meditators have goals** like controlling mind and thoughts,etc,...
- Both of them have **Motives** and **Benefits** so i cannot experience the difference.

**MY QUESTION :**

- What is the difference between Penance and Meditation ?

Comment: Penance (Tapas or voluntary suffering) need not be only in the form of meditation. Doing your own duty without expecting rewards is itself a penance. Fasting is a penance. Going to gym or studying late night, are all penance. Sitting in middle of 5 fires is a penance. Both Vishvamitra and Ravana did hard penance, each with different goals. Whereas meditation could be just one type of penance, or not even that if done without a motive.. just like breathing.

Comment: @ram friend If we do penance(doing our duty) then we will get good karma but lord krishna said do your duty not expecting results you will be realesed from good or bad karma

Comment: penance can have different goals. by kamya karma, penance will give good karma. by niskhamya karma, penance will give moksha.